# Is there an algorithm that finds pattern in seemingly random list of strings?

Tags: algorithm, cracking

**Intro**

Some time ago there was a giveaway that a certain company producing beverages made: you could buy a product and within the bottle you would get a 10 letter-and-number code that you could enter online and possibly win a prize. I myself liked that drink so whenever I bought one I would use the code. It happened that one of those codes was winning and I saved it. Later on I found out that my friend also won a prize, so out of interest I asked him for his code. When comparing the two, I discovered that ASCII codes of those two winning codes' characters added to a certain number. Trying my other non-winning ones, I found that none of them satisfied the ASCII code criteria, but they all fell within the certain range (I'm not sure what it is).

I tried typing random codes but it turned out that none of those were valid (not non-winning, but rather weren't accepted by the system at all). So I thought that it must be one of the two:

- They had pre-prepared list of codes (which's length I guess is measured in millions since the drink is very popular) and only some of them are winning (also pre-determined).
- The system tested each code for some specific criteria to establish whether it comes from the actual product or is randomly typed.

**Question**

So, this got me thinking: *"Is there an algorithm that takes a list of such codes and tries to find a rule that all of them are following?"*

Sadly, I'm not familiar with any algorithms (C, Haskell, Prolog...) that are able to do this, so I'm asking here. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this since I am as well a computer science student and the existence of such an algorithm (or anything for that matter that is related to my question) could help me in the future.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: looks like a perfect fit for an neuronal network

Comment: @Hexception Thank you for helping! Since I have not yet come in touch with anything similar, can you please recommend something to start with (some _extremely_ simplified explanations, or possibly an online tool?), so I can research this topic a little closer? I've looked it up online but was not able to find anything that I can understand, let alone implement for this example...

Comment: Yeah there are plenty of tutorials on youtube e.g.: https://youtu.be/tPYj3fFJGjk. But keep in mind that that it will probably take you some time to archive what you are trying to do